# Flutter GetX Auth ever function

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, get, flutter-getx

I am completely new to GetX and want to learn an easier state management system than bloc ( I started with BLoC). So the first thing I wanted to learn is how authentication works. I found this tutorial online: https://dev.to/imransefat/firebase-authentication-with-getx-in-flutter-4ik8 and asked me a question.
Inside the controller, the author bound two streams. One for the user and one for the googleSignInUser and he also added an ever function for googleSignIn:

```
googleSignInAccount.bindStream(googleSign.onCurrentUserChanged);
    ever(googleSignInAccount, _setInitialScreenGoogle);
```

. When I user exactly this source-code and add a Firestore crud controller with a Todo-list, I get a null value on the variable `auth.currentUser!` on the Stream for the Todo list ( `firebaseFirestore.collection('/users/${**auth.currentUser!**.uid}/FoodList').snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot query) {...` )

When I remove this function inside the onReady method, everything works fine. If I understand this correctly, I don't have to listen to the googleSignIn stream specifically, it should be enough to listen to the user stream. Is this a mistake from him, or do I misunderstand here something? You can find the complete source code on the website.

Second question is: Before GetX I always check if a user is authenticated or not with a StreamBuilder inside the Material app:

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: auth.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const RootPage();
            } else {
              return TutorialRoot();
            }
```

With GetX I saw this appoach with the `_setInitialScreen(User? user)` method and the

```
 ever(firebaseUser, _setInitialScreen);
```

call inside the onReady(); - Is the StreamBuilder a bad practice when using GetX, or still a legit way of checking the current auth status? In my opinion the user expirince is a little bit faster with the StreamBuilder that why I ask for this.